# modify nested object but maintain the full object after

Tags: jq

I need to modify an element --an array-- (e.g.: "group-xyz") within a nested object in a JSON tree using JQ but once that's done then I need the entire object back with the modified data.

The goal is to update a JSON tree and save it in full.
e.g.: add array element, empty array, etc.

```
{
  "group-abc": {"users": ["tina.turner"]},
  "group-def": {"users": ["someone.else"]},
  "group-xyz": {"users": ["that.thing"]
}
```

Then I am interested in returning an object like this:

```
{
  "group-abc": {"users": ["tina.turner"]},
  "group-def": {"users": []},
  "group-xyz": {"users": ["that.thing","well.done"]
}
```

Comment: What have you tried to accomplish this? Adding some code examples to your question helps! :-) See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more info

Comment: did you even care to look at the reviewed issue and the answer I gave? I guess some people just need to talk instead of doing something about.

Comment: Before you accuse someone of something it's worth checking out their point of view. When using the review queue you can't see the answers as it's about the question and the question is flawed. Another thing to note is the how-to-ask page. Good that you found an answer, shame it comes with an attitude.

Answer (score 1):

I have changed my requirements to fit a more complex form. To add a user to any of these groups' users this is what I did:

```
jq '. |= map( if ( .group=="abc") then .users+=["final.answer",] else . end)' source.json
```

which produced a result

```
[
    {
        "group": "abc",
        "users": [
            "user1",
            "user2",
            "final.answer"
        ]
    },
    {
        "group": "def",
        "users": [
            "user4",
            "user5"
        ]
    }
]
```